# как очистить консольное окно из скрипта python

Tags: linux, windows

Доброго вре ени суток,
В windows есть **CLS**. В linux есть **CLEAR**. А как это сделать с
**python** крос платфтормено ?

Comment: Можно написать метод, который определяет текущую ОС, используя что-то вроде `os.name`, `sys.platform` или `os.uname()`, и вызывает соответствующую команду.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отчистит экран и в Windows и в Linux и в BSD и даже в MacOS

```
import os

# Для поддержки VT100 в Windows
os.system('')

# Отчистит экран
print('\x1b[2J')

# Поднимет курсор в левый верхний угол
print('\x1b[H')
```

Comment: Я совсем забыл про **ANSI ESCAPE SEQUENCE** =)  [ссылка]https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI[ссылка]

Comment: Ответ неверный, точнее уж сильно узконаправленный. Надо подключать библиотеку terminfo.

Comment: @0andriy не нужно подключать никаких библиотек. работает без зависимостей в том виде как есть.

Comment: У меня не работает. Может это неочевидно, но эти последовательности определяются исключительно типом терминала. То, что у вас работает, совсем не значит, что это будет работать всегда и везде.

Comment: @0andriy эти последовательности присутствуют в VT100. На терминалы старее VT100 вряд ли найдется эмулятор. В более новых терминалах последовательность работала. Я не понимаю, какой терминал эмулируете вы, что у вас не работает последовательности VT100?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать проверку:

```
import os
import platform

command = ""

system = platform.system()
if system == "Windows":
    command = "cls"
elif system == "Linux":
    command = "clear"
os.system(command)
```

Comment: Я совсем забыл про **ANSI ESCAPE SEQUENCE**  [ссылка](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_ANSI)

Comment: Это не по-питоновски.